# Piping tar archive via mv on macOS

Tags: pipe, tar

I ran:

```
tar -cjvf ~/Dict_$(date +%Y-%m_%d-%H_%M_%S).tar.bz2 ~/Dictionaries | xargs mv ~/Documents
```

but it leaves the resulting file in `~/` and does not move it.

How do I move the resulting file (after it was archived) to another folder?

Comment: What file do you want to move? `~/Dict_$(date +%Y-%m_%d-%H_%M_%S).tar.bz2`? Or `~/Dictionaries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the output? 
Did it say something like

```
mv: target ‘some filename’ is not a directory
```

?

In general, if *`cmd`* outputs `a`, `b` and `c`, and you run

```
cmd | xargs d e f
```

then `xargs` will run

```
d e f a b c
```

So your command caused `xargs` to run

```
mv ~/Documents file1 file2 file3 …
```

That’s not how `mv` works.

Try

```
(your tar command)  |  xargs mv -t ~/Documents
```

Note: you should probably first verify that the version of `mv`
on your system supports the `-t` option. 
If you were on Linux, it would be pretty much guaranteed,
but I’m not sure about macOS.